# How to see the cases associated with a knowledge article from knowledge article record in Lightning?

Tags: lightning, case, knowledge

We use knowledge lightning and we can attach articles to the case object using Knowledge Component on Flexi Page. So we can see related list with articles on Case record. Is there any way how we can see on Article record related list with Cases to which current article is attached? The only way I see how to make it work is to use standard junction object CaseArticle and create component which will display the related list. Any thoughts? Is there any standard functionality? I believe it was possible in classic with "Enable list of cases linked to an article in Salesforce Classic (Classic Only)" checkbox enabled. Related list with cases was added automatically to article page in classic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this in a Trailhead org. You will need to put the Cases object in the Related List on the Lightning Knowledge Detail Page Layout for each of your record types. Once you do that and also have the Related Cases Component on your Lightning Page Layouts, Cases which have Knowledge Articles of that record type will show up on an article's Case Related List. There's no need for a junction object. It's just a matter of completing your standard configuration steps so that everything that's needed is there.

Comment: There is no Case object to choose  in Related Lists on Knowledge__kav layout ..

Comment: Well, I just had to give Allow users to create an article from a case (Classic Only) permissions in Knwoledge Settings